# Windows isn't booting, I'm not being allowed to use a dvd or usb to boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot

I have an Asus n56v (notebook) (the bios has this uefi and csm options for booting which I have used a few times already).

I can't seem to boot from neither dvds nor usbs. How can I manage to install Windows?

Edit: I have installed Windows in this computer before, I used both USB and DVDs...

Edit2: I have another notebook, maybe I should try to swap the hard drives. Then I could install Windows. Then swap again...

When I try to boot from a Windows 7 or 8 DVD, it's just not recognized ("Reboot and select proper boot device or...).

When I try to boot a Windows 7 USB, I get a "Windows failed to start" black screen.
Windows 10 USB and I get similar errors.

Comment: Have you ever installed using USB earlier ?

Comment: "How can I manage to install Windows?" - Create a UEFI enabled bootable disk.  Be sure you disaable CSM when you do that.  If you are USB device sure it USB 2.0 instead of USB 3.0 if you are installing Windows 7